# Using GitNub with Git

Tags: git, github, gitnub

I'm trying to use GitNub, a graphical GUI for Git, and for some reason upon installing the software running the command 'nub' in the terminal doesn't seem to launch anything for me.

I am running Mac OS X version 10.6.3

Gitnub version 0.9.1

I have copied the GitNub.app to my applications folder and created a new folder under /usr/local/ called "bin" to put the 'nub' executable inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

May be [ticket 51](https://activereload.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8791/tickets/51-gitnubapp-should-install-itself-on-launch) might help:

> The installation process of GitNub.app (and nub) is awkward.
>
> Instead of having the user install from a zipped folder, we should move nub into `GitNub.app/Contents/Resources/nub` and offer to install a symlink on the first launch.
> The dialog should offer to install to `~/bin` by default if it exists, otherwise defaulting to `/usr/local/bin`, and offer the macports `/opt/local/bin`, and `fink /sw/bin` if they exist.
> The user should be able to choose a location as well. Only show this dialog on the first launch.

The steps mentioned above for an "ideal" installation might help you spot what you missed with your own installation process.